# Team Foundation Server and VB6 Checking In Issue - VB6 thinks that one project relates to another

Tags: vb6, projects-and-solutions, msscci

We have VB6 & TFS2010 installed on our corporate system. 
The issue arises when we try to open or check in a project file in VB6 through MSSCCI provider that connects to TFS2010. 
We have two separate projects Project 1 & Project 2 (which is a copy of project 1). These two projects are under the same collection. In my local drive they have the following structure.

C:\TFS\Project1

C:\TFS\Project2

I have previously opened CIS_DL.vbp  from C:\TFS\Project1 relating to Project1 in TFS.
 The first time I opened the project file CIS_DL.vbp in project 1 folder I was asked by VB6/TFS whether I wanted to add that project file to the Source Control - I have then added that project file to Source Control and Project 1 works fine. That is opening project/check in/out project works okay.

Now when I open the project file(CIS_DL.vbp) located in C:\TFS\Project2  (this project file is identical to project file located in project 1) VB6 MSSCCI provider thinks that the project file as well as all the other code relates to project1 in TFS2010 .

**TEAM FOUNDATION PROJECT PROPERTIES IN VB6** 
When I open VB6 and  go to  Tools…Team Foundation…Team Foundation Properties below information is displayed:

Server Name: $\project 1\CIS_DL.vbp ( It should read $\project 2\CIS_DL.vbp)

Local Name: C:\TFS\Project 1\CIS_DL.vbp (it should read   C:\TFS\Project2\CIS_DL.vbp)

**TEAM FOUNDATION PROJECT PROPERTIES IN VS2010 *(TFS TEAM EXPLORER)**
When I go to $\project 2\CIS_DL.vbp right click on it and select properties I get

Server Name: refers to $\project 2\CIS_DL.vbp (CORRECT)

Local Name: C:\TFS\Project 2\CIS_DL.vbp (CORRECT)
It also lets me check in/out without any issues as far as I can tell.

Is there a way that these two projects can be separated so that the MSSCCI provider can distinguish between the two different projects even though they are the identical copy of each other? Also how does TFS handle VB6 project files?
There is a story behind why we need an identical copy of the code i.e. Copy of project1, so having only one project is not a solution for us.

**I have tried the following:**

1. In TFS2010 under File...Source Control...Workspaces changing and playing around with my workspace and mapping the different projects to different locations. This did not help.
2. In the local source folder (c:\TFS\Project 2) renaming the project file to something else. When i opened the project file it asked me whether or not i wanted to add it to source control. I clicked on Yes and that then added the file to the project1 location in TFS

I am open to suggestions. Also happy to provide screenshots someone can point to a location where I can upload them.

Many thanks

Dalibor

Comment: add screenshots using image button in toolbar when you will edit post

Comment: +1. I am having a similar problem, so its not just you. I resorted to making a copy of my VB6 development environment (which is running in a vmware image) into another completely seperate vmware image and running it from there. Couldn't get TFS to check files out to the correct directory when both projects were on the same machine.

Comment: Did you copy Project 1 to Project 2 before or after you added Project 1 to source control?

Comment: Not helpful I know, but - Ick. I would have expected TFS to have moved on but I remember problems like this with Visual SourceSafe 6.0. I know that corporate types like to use it (because it's perceived to be "free" with other products from MS), but I really would consider a better designed VCS (and totally understand why this isn't a helpful comment and why you might not have the option..)